# How to get cell location of all matches in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of data with row and column labels, as seen below:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2.2 | 1.4 | 0.7 | 0.3 |
| B | 2.2 | 0 | 1.0 | 1.4 | 2.0 |
| C | 1.4 | 1.0 | 0 | 2.3 | 4.9 |
| D | 0.7 | 1.4 | 2.3 | 0 | 4.3 |
| E | 0.3 | 2.0 | 4.9 | 4.3 | 0 |

As seen in the table, the numbers are a combination of the letters.  I need to find all letter combinations over 2; in this case, AB, CD, CE, and DE.  The order does not matter.

Using `=FILTER($B$2:$B$6, $B$2:$B$6>2)` for each excel column from `B` to `F` (corresponding to `A` to `E` in the table), I can find all the match numbers.  How can I get the cell locations or the column values instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it all in one function using dynamic arrays:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, MAKEARRAY(5,5,LAMBDA(r,c,IF((INDEX(B2:F6,r,c)>2)*( INDEX(A2:A6,r)>INDEX(B1:F1,c)), INDEX(A2:A6,r)&INDEX(B1:F1,c),""))))`

Answer (score 1):

```
I1= =IF(B2:B6>2;"A"&INDEX($A$1:$A$6;ROW(INDEX(B2:B6;)));"")
J2= =IF(C2:C6>2;"B"&INDEX($A$1:$A$6;ROW(INDEX(C2:C6;)));"")


I8= =FILTER(I1#;I1#<>"")
J8= =FILTER(J1#;J1#<>"")


I12=    =TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;$I$1:$M$5)
```

[image]